# How to Call a non launcher class from GcmListenerService?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am learning the gcm integration part in android and i came across this issue, where I am unable to call an activity which is not marked as a launcher in the manifest. I am able to receive the gcm notification and all the data, but unable to call the activity. Why is this happening? And i face this issue only when the app is removed from background. Is there a way to store and retreive the application context when the app is not running or removed from background?

```
public class NotificationsListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    public static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 435345;
    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        //String message = data.getString("message");
        String message = data.getBundle("notification").getString("body");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
        Log.d(TAG, "GCM DATA: " + data);

        try{
            String CODE=data.getString("code");
            if(CODE!=null){
                switch (CODE){
                    case "666":
                        String id=data.getString("id");
                        Code666(id);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void Code666(String _id) {
        Context context = getBaseContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("_id",_id);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.floatinglogo)
                .setContentTitle("Horn OK")
                .setContentText("HelpNeeded!")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Sidharth

Comment: try with `flag_activity_new task` something.

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: Please post the code where you are sending the pending intent and showing notification.

Comment: hey, thanks for the responses guys. i have edited the question and inserted the code

Comment: So the thing is the SecondActivity.java is not the default launcher class

Comment: did you try with .. `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`?

Comment: yes i tried, but still no result. I want to call the SecondActivity.class, but when i set new task as intent flag the launcher class is getting called!

Comment: Is there nay code in your `SecondActivity` that redirects user to your `LauncherActivity` ?

Comment: @PrerakSola nope, no such code which will redirect to launcher activity

Answer (score 0):

add these two lines in the intent

```
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

I am using this method and it works fine, HomeActivity is not my launcher activity

```
private void sendNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to store the application context while closing the app?

Comment: edited my answer please check this works properly for me.